# Old Macbook (white plastic body Macbook 3,1) with Ubuntu shows grub shell when booting

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi, 32bit

I have an old Macbook (white plastic body Macbook 3,1) which I use for driving my telescope. Recently I installed Astronomy Linux (Ubuntu) on it (https://sourceforge.net/projects/astronomy-linux-21-04/) by following these instructions: https://mesom.de/efi32boot/index.html

I could get it installed correctly, but after rebooting, instead of booting directly, the mac shows me a grub shell.

By reading the comments on the installation instructions I followed, I learned by trial and error that, in my case, in order to have my system booting I have to enter the following commands at that shell:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt2)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd /boot/initrd
grub> boot
```

and then it boots correctly.

To be honest, I do not fully understand what I am doing, I just blindly copied the instructions I found :( There is no OS-X on it, just this Ubuntu distribution I downloaded from internet. I have tried to fix this behavior, once logged in, by doing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

but nothing changed after the reboot. I have heard those old Macbooks have an Intel Core 2 Duo 64 bit CPU but a 32 bit EFI, which might by the culprit.

Is there a way to fix all this and make my mac booting by itself?

Thanks

Erik

Comment: Just for clarification, I was able to install Linux and then boot it by using those grub commands. The problem it just that it does not boot by itself.

Comment: It sounds like the 3-line `grub.cfg` in your EFI partition (which should be mounted as `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`) contains the wrong UUID or partition and sets an incorrect root variable and path to your main grub config `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. That's the one you set with `set root=(hd0,gpt2)`. Please add the output of `sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` and `lsblk -f` to the question.

Comment: Meanwhile I was waiting for an answer, I tried to proceed myself. In the end, I kind of fixed my situation by booting using the command sequence I mentioned and later by upgrading 22.04 within Ubuntu 21.04 (Astronomy Linux is 21.04). By doing so something changed: now I can boot almost regularly without the need for manually booting. Sometimes it still hangs (black screen) during the boot, but it looks like that when it does I first have some text messages during the boot phase suggesting there are problems with the wifi interface (it can't find its drivers, hence I cannot use it).

Comment: I can provide what Freddy was asking for, but the output is long: should I edit my original question of should I write an answer to myself in order to proceed that way? However, I don't know if this is still relevant, according to what I said in my last comment.

Comment: Well, it seems to be fixed now. The contents of `grub.cfg` in your ESP is only 3 lines long and I wanted to compare the UUID with `lsblk -F`'s output. I guess the file is overwritten now. You may write an answer if the problem is gone. I think wifi should be fixable.

Comment: For completeness, my grub.cfg now is:
`search.fs_uuid d49bd0ae-d2b1-4063-ad96-691b7a17f166 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg`
and the UUID from `lsblk -f` is the same of what is in the grub.cfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try answering myself.

First I realized that the instructions reported here:  https://mesom.de/efi32boot/index.html are **not** for a Macbook 3,1 but for a Macbook 2,1. Therefore they do not apply to my case, instead in the end I was able to install Astronomy Linux on my old Macbook 3,1 simply by flashing a USB flash drive using [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher) and the image found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/astronomy-linux-21-04/

But still the problem remained as originally described. At some point Ubuntu Astronomy Linux, once logged in through the manual procedure I described, proposed me to upgrade to 22.04 (Astronomy Linux is 21.04). The reason for which I was not upgrading was that by doing so, the upgrades somehow removed the old drivers for firewire cameras as well as some software related to those cameras (this is why I wanted to install such old distribution: I have an old but good firewire astronomic CCD camera which I wanted to continue using with my telescope, and that distribution has good software for it).

By upgrading, I was able to fix my issue but at the cost of loosing the old drivers for the camera (firewire now is deprecated. There are some "new" firewire drivers available in Ubuntu: I tried installing them, but they do not work in my case for reasons I could not fully understand and probably off-topic here).

But after several trials and errors, I realized I could do the upgrade to the 22.04 telling Ubuntu (in the popup menu that proposed me to upgrade) **to install new things** but to **not delete the old libraries and packages**. I also specifically selected to not upgrade grub and the grub configuration (I do not know if that was good or not, I was scared that such upgrade could spoil something).

So, by doing all this I was able to fix the problem originally described in this question: now the system boots by itself without manual procedures, **and** I have my old dear firewire CCD astronomic camera working!

Comment: P.S. Why do I had such an interest for that old Macbook? Simply because it has a firewire port, so I could use it for my old astronomic firewire CCD: they are quite expensive, it is such a waste trashing them away when they are still working fine just because firewire has been deprecated :)